# How do I solve error in executing seq function?

Tags: r, dataframe, seq

I am running the following code, in order to get all the dates from 22th of jan 2014 untill the second of feb 2014. However, I get an error that I do not understand (as I follow the code on the page of the function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/seq.Date)

```
seq(as.Date("22/01/2014"), as.Date("02/02/2014"), "days")
```

gives me the following error:

```
 Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: The problem is with your `Date` format. Try `seq(as.Date("2014/01/22"), as.Date("2014/02/02"), by = "days")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try debugging your code. Does every part resolve as you expect? Compare to the examples and see which differences there are:

```
Them: seq(as.Date("1910/1/1"), as.Date("1999/1/1"), "days")
You   seq(as.Date("22/01/2014"), as.Date("02/02/2014"), "days")
```

Can you run the example? If not, something sinister is going on in your environment.

Does your code match the example? Try modifying the example, one part at a time, to match what you are trying to.

Perhaps it's the date format. Try executing a small part of the code:

```
as.Date("22/01/2014")
[1] "0022-01-20"
```

Does this look right? Perhaps  `as.Date` doesn't understand American date formats.  Try modifying your code:

```
seq(as.Date("2014-01-22"), as.Date("2014-02-02"), by="days")
[1] "2014-01-22" "2014-01-23" "2014-01-24" "2014-01-25" "2014-01-26" "2014-01-27" "2014-01-28" "2014-01-29" "2014-01-30" "2014-01-31" "2014-02-01"
[12] "2014-02-02"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try some of this options:

```
seq.Date(as.Date("2014/01/22"), as.Date("2014/02/02"), by="days")
seq.Date(as.Date("22/01/2014", format="%d/%m/%Y"), as.Date("02/02/2014", format="%d/%m/%Y"), by="days")
seq(as.Date("2014/01/22"), as.Date("2014/02/02"), by="days")
seq(as.Date("22/01/2014", format="%d/%m/%Y"), as.Date("02/02/2014", format="%d/%m/%Y"), by="days")
```